# Find the relationship between these two words

Tags: synonyms

I need to know the relationship of two words for a computer programming problem.

So for example, dog and cat are mammals and animals. Fork and spoon are silverware. GameCube and PlayStation are video game consoles. And so on and so on.

What are the relationship between these words?
Enter and Exit.
Join and Quit.
Coming and Going.

I was thinking the relationship between the words above is presence. But this seems clunky to me. Does anyone have a better suggestion?

Thank you!

Comment: Are we talking about the relationships of the words in each pair or the relationship between the pairs of words? If the latter, does _antonyms_ work?

Comment: I updated the question to improve the formatting. Looking for the relationship between enter and exit. Not sure if this would also be considered some type of grouping as the examples are provided above. Truck and car are automobiles. Grass and tree's are plants. etc

Comment: How about *direction*?

Comment: The examples you're asking about have a relationship of a different nature from the first set of examples, in that they are opposed to one another.

Comment: Fairly off-topic, but if you're working with words and relationships between them, without knowing the actual project, you might want to check out word-to-vec and wordnet

Comment: Btw, there's also a linguistics site on Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You're looking for [hypernyms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyponymy_and_hypernymy).

> **hypernym** *noun*
>   A word with a broad meaning constituting a category into which words with more specific meanings fall; a superordinate. For example, colour is a hypernym of red.
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hypernym)

Consider the following:

- enter and exit are forms of *access*;
- join and quit are types of *membership-change requests*; and
- coming and going are types of *travel*.

Comment: Good, simple answer to a great question.

Comment: And here I was thinking he wanted antonyms.  Thoughtful answer.

Comment: Learned something new, cheers! & if the OP is looking for the relationship between the pairs, they would be "co-hyponyms", according to the linked Wiki page: *Co-hyponyms are labelled as such when separate hyponyms share the same hypernym but are not hyponyms of one another, unless they happen to be synonymous. For example, screwdriver, scissors, knife, hammer are all co-hyponyms of tool, but not hyponyms of one another*